# Installing a repair kit on an old toilet

Tags: plumbing

I'm looking to install a repair kit on an old toilet (to replace the dual flush conversion which just doesn't work). I have a [korky complete toilet repair kit](http://www.lowes.com/pd_103048-868-4010CM_0__?k_clickID=5eade5a8-4515-4087-960c-495b61cbecb5&store_code=2450&productId=3130073&selectedLocalStoreBeanArray=[com.lowes.commerce.storelocator.beans.LocatorStoreBean%407b547b54]&storeNumber=2450&kpid=3130073&kpid=3130073&cm_mmc=SCE_PLA-_-RoughPlumbingElectrical-_-ToiletRepair-_-3130073%3AKorky&DM_PersistentCookieCreated=true&CAWELAID=&CAWELAID=1024204353) which includes a fill valve and a flush valve, but looking at my toilet I'm not sure this will even work. The flush valve in particular has a screw thread end and a sponge gasket, but my toilet has a metal pipe between the bowl and the tank, which appears to end at the tank with a screw thread of it's own.

Is it possible to make these work together or do I need something else for a toilet of this vintage?

Also note: the tank is actually bolted to the wall!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your picture is not showing up, try uploading it again.

Comment: @WarLoki: Ah, now it's working. It might be because it complained about the size the first time, but then it wouldn't even let me upload the resized image. Here's the view inside and outside the tank.

Comment: Do you know the manufacture of the toilet?

Comment: @WarLoki: On the bowl it says "Standard" ejecto. In fact, it's [exactly like this one](https://www.flickr.com/photos/weffie/3662234571)

Answer (score 1):

What you have may not work. The Douglas valve or flush valve (The brass looking piece in your toilet) extend through the toilet and the Ell goes into the valve and the whole thing setts with  a nut. If the repair kits flush valve does not have enough to set, go through the tank, allow the ell to set and screw down with a nut, it is not going work. You may need to go to a plumbing store and get the correct kit for your toilet.

Comment: Thanks, that's my fear. I think I might be calling a professional to deal with it. Something this old, I'm not too keen on getting stuck with a non-working toilet.