# 1920s Standard Ejecto repair - results or advice?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, antique, american-standard

Working on my 1928ish Standard Ejecto toilet with a low mount tank. I am facing the same situation as Matt Burland in the following post: [Installing a repair kit on an old toilet](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/72013/170076)

He did not post a follow up but I kinda think that set may work if I manage to remove the tank.
Has anyone experience with vintage toilets? Can I proceed or must I replace the L tube between basin and tank? Could this be a catastrophic outcome?

I really appreciate your counsel. We're in a 1 bath so I need to power through the repair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Flush valve repair kit](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Fluidmaster-PerforMAX-2-in-Plastic-Toilet-Flapper-Repair-Kit/1000085205?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-plb-_-ggl-_-LIA_PLB_208_Plumbing-Repair-_-1000085205-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=CjwKCAjwh8mlBhB_EiwAsztdBEe53bN_kYmIy4IXqJ6HMb5zuOVLOhNWgbhxw0g2Xy34m42zgyGKihoC1_4QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) should work.

It is glued onto the tube seat and had it's own pivot for the valve.

I have use them before on old toilets with worn flush valve seats. It worked well for years. When the flapper needs to be replaced it can be done with the standard flapper.

Comment: could be region blocking but the link dosen't work for me

Comment: @JGOS, it works here fine.  I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: You can probably google “Fluidmaster PerforMAX 2-in Plastic Toilet Flapper Repair Kit”

Comment: @RMDman Thank you!! Can I proceed with dismantling the toilet or should I wait and get a new L tube thingy?